# Telerik WPF GridView get SelectedItems of GridView in a GridView

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, telerik, hierarchy

I have a Telerik WPF GridView which has a Gridview as HierarchyChildTemplate.

When I expand one row in the upper hierarchy, I can select rows in the lower hierarchy. Now I want to click a button and on the button_click event I want to access the SelectedItems. Does anyone know how to get there?

Thank you for the help.

**EDIT**

I got the solution for my problem:

1. Subscribe to the SelectionChanged event of the child GridView
2. In the event handler the sender will be the current child GridView
3. Store actual SelectedItems of the child GridView in an instance variable
4. Use stored SelectedItems when needed

   ```
   private void SubGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangeEventArgs e)
   {
       var subGrid = (RadGridView) sender;
       _subGridSelectedItems = subGrid.SelectedItems;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the SelectedItems property of the child grid in the click handler of the button.

If your child grid is named childGrid you can access the selected rows like this:

```
var selectedRows = childGrid.SelectedItems;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but that doesn't work. I cannot access the child grid by its name. I don't know why :-(